# Can't create two instances of one object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I created this piece of code to render some animation. This seems to work just fine for one animation. However if I try to create two or more instances of the object everything gets mixed up and nothing will render anymore.

```
var animate = function(id,sprite){
var sprites = sprite;
var imageID = id;
var arize = document.getElementById(imageID);   
var spriteID;
var animationSprites;

console.log("before switch: sprite: " + sprite + "imageID: " + imageID + "element: " + arize + "animationSprites: " + animationSprites)

switch(sprites) {
    case "appear":
        animationSprites = appear;
        spriteID = "appear";
        break;
    case "die":
        animationSprites = die;
        spriteID = "die";
        break;
    case "slap":
        animationSprites = slap;
        spriteID = "slap";
        break;
    case "walk":
        animationSprites = walk;
        spriteID = "walk";
        break;
    default:
        animationSprites = idle;
        spriteID = "idle";
}

console.log(sprites.length)
console.log("after switch: sprite: " + sprite + "imageID: " + imageID + "element: " + arize + "animationSprites: " + animationSprites)

this.animateThis = function() {

    arize.src = animationSprites[i];
    i++;    
    setTimeout(function() {         
        if (i < animationSprites.length) {   
            console.log(i)
            showings(); 
            if (i== animationSprites.length -1) {
               i=0;
            }       
        }
    },50);
}

function showings() {
    var showZombieTwo = new animate("imgs", "slap");
    showZombieTwo.animateThis();
    //var showZombieOne = new animate("imgs1", "idle");
    //showZombieOne.animateThis();
}
```

How can I render multiple animations at the same time?

Comment: @freedomn-m those are arrays with pictures

Answer (score 0):

The `showing` function is inside the `animate` function, meaning animating a single sprite animates all of them. Of course, this works when there is one of them, but only one.

I rewrote a bit the code to make it easy to switch from an animation to another, as i supposed that was the initial intent.

Also can you tell what was the `spriteID` variable for? I see no use of it anywhere in the code.

```
// assumed variables
var i = 0,
  appear = [/* array of src strings */],
  die = [/* array of src strings */],
  slap = [/* array of src strings */],
  walk = [/* array of src strings */];


var animate = function(imageID, sprite) {
  var that = this;
  var sprites = sprite;
  var arize = document.getElementById(imageID);
  var spriteID; // What is the purpose of this variable?
  var animationSprites;

  console.log("before switch: sprite: " + sprite + "imageID: " + imageID + "element: " + arize + "animationSprites: " + animationSprites);

  this.currentAnimationFrame = 0;

  this.setCurrentAnimation = function(animationName) {
    // reset animation
    that.currentAnimationFrame = 0;

    switch (animationName) {
      case "appear":
        animationSprites = appear;
        spriteID = "appear";
      break;
      case "die":
        animationSprites = die;
        spriteID = "die";
      break;
      case "slap":
        animationSprites = slap;
        spriteID = "slap";
      break;
      case "walk":
        animationSprites = walk;
        spriteID = "walk";
      break;
      default:
        animationSprites = idle;
        spriteID = "idle";
    }

    return spriteID;
  }

  this.animateThis = function() {
    arize.src = animationSprites[that.currentAnimationFrame];
    that.currentAnimationFrame++;

    setTimeout(function() {
      if (that.currentAnimationFrame >= animationSprites.length) {
        that.currentAnimationFrame = 0;
      }
      that.animateThis();
    }, 50);
  }

  // setting the init animation
  this.setCurrentAnimation(sprite);
}

var showZombieTwo = new animate("imgs", "slap");
showZombieTwo.animateThis();

// braaaain
showZombieTwo.setCurrentAnimation("walk");

// finally...
showZombieTwo.setCurrentAnimation("die");
```

Comment: this i variable is defined above the function like so:
var i =0;
var animate = function(id,sprite){
//code
}

Comment: Ah, then yes, `i` is shared between each `animate` object. Can you try moving it inside the `animate` function definition to make it local?

Comment: i still cant get it to work with multiple instances at once, it still works just fine with a single instance tho.. im still working on a fix, moving the i variable didnt solve the problem

Comment: After reading again your code I edited my answer, I think it is closer to what you want to do.